# In Pandas dataframe, drop rows based on multiple conditions (with fixed ID)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to drop rows in a dataframe based on multiple conditions?

For fixed ID and giving precedence to ColB, I would like to drop rows based these conditions:

- If ColA and ColB values exists for a specific ID, then drop ColA rows for that ID
- If ColA only exists for an ID then do nothing

Example df:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You must provide input as text. [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: It would be great to provide other examples  to see how the logic generalizes (more than two rows per ID, all NaNs, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create mask for get all rows if no missing values in both columns, filter `ID`s by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), get rows with no match `ID`s by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
m = df[['ColA','ColB']].notna().all(axis=1)

out = pd.concat([df[~df['ID'].isin(df.loc[m, 'ID'])], df[m]]).sort_index()
print (out)
   ID ColA    ColB
1   1  bbb  yellow
2   2  fpo     NaN
3   3  ost    blue
```

Another idea:

```
cols = ['ColA','ColB']
f = lambda x: x.dropna(subset=cols) if x[cols].notna().all(axis=1).any() else x
out = df.groupby('ID',group_keys=False ).apply(f)
print (out)
   ID ColA    ColB
1   1  bbb  yellow
2   2  fpo     NaN
3   3  ost    blue
```

Or:

```
m = df[['ColA','ColB']].ne('').all(axis=1)

out = pd.concat([df[~df['ID'].isin(df.loc[m, 'ID'])], df[m]]).sort_index()
print (out)
   ID ColA    ColB
1   1  bbb  yellow
2   2  fpo        
3   3  ost    blue
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have up to two options per ID, a simple solution is to [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to push the empty strings/NaNs on top, then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
out = (df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'ColB'], na_position='first')
         .drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
      )
```

Otherwise use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with two masks:

```
m1 = df['ColB'].replace('', float('nan')).notna()
m2 = ~df['ID'].duplicated(keep=False)

out = df[m1|m2]
```

Output:

```
  ID ColA    ColB
1  1  bbb  yellow
2  2  fpo        
3  3  ost    blue
```